# Modify Existing decimal places info

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table StudentInfo

```
  StudentID  HDT      Code   NAME  
    1233    3300    100.01   Jorge
    1234    3301    1233.01  Steve
    1235    3300    155.32   Jessica
    5536    3300    568.22   Tim
```

For HDTYPID 3300 I want to add 0 in the decimal place

```
  StudentID  HDT      Code   NAME   
    1233    3300    100.001   Jorge
    1234    3301    1233.01  Steve
    1235    3300    155.032   Jessica
    5536    3300    568.022   Tim
```

I tried with the format but it doesn't add 0

Comment: FORMAT is useless here because you want to change values. Why no change on the second row ?

Comment: second-row HDTYPID is 3301. I only need change for HDTPID 3300

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. We shouldn't need to guess at datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way with a string.

```
UPDATE StudentInfo
SET HDCOD=REPLACE(HDCOD,'.','.0')
WHERE HDTYPID=3300
```

Comment: I'm so bad, you got this, good job. Was trying so hard with stupid cast ...