# Modify Existing decimal places in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table StudentInfo

```
  StudentID  HDT      Code        NAME  
    1233    3300    CR100.0001   Jorge
    1353    3300    CR400.0002   Jorge
    1235    3300    WE1554.002   Jessica
    5536    3300    WE568.002      Tim
    1234    3301    QA1233.001    Steve
    1235    3300    WE1554.002   Jessica
    5536    3300    WE568.002      Tim
```

For HDT 3300 I want to remove 0 in the decimal place. It should be CR100.001

```
      StudentID  HDT      Code        NAME  
        1233    3300    CR100.001   Jorge
        1353    3300    CR400.002   Jorge
        1235    3300    WE1554.002   Jessica
        5536    3300    WE568.002      Tim
        1234    3301    QA1233.001    Steve
        1235    3300    WE1554.002   Jessica
        5536    3300    WE568.002      Tim
```

The Problem is HDT 3300 has several records with three decimals and four decimals . not sure how to change only particular records for HDT 3300. Any Suggestion?

Comment: You want this to be permanent (i.e. update the table) or just within the Select query?
And what database are you working with - some DBs have a wider set of String functions.

Comment: SQL Server 2014?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128154/modify-existing-decimal-places-info (you need just adjust the query on the linked question and change the like). Why you added a zero and now removing?

Comment: I'm removing 0 here @SebastianBrosch

Answer (score 3):

If you want this permanently changed:

```
UPDATE StudentInfo
    SET Code = REPLACE(Code, '.0', '.')
    WHERE HDT = 3300 AND Code LIKE '%.000_';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ae59d21d92ee6db5402b2bea4bf39927) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that this works.

Comment: It hasn't changed anything on the decimal places. still showing four decimal digits

Comment: Although the sample data doesn't happen to include it, this will shorten "BR549.000" to "BR549.00" since the trailing wildcard (`%`) will match zero or more characters.

Comment: @Johnson . . . Is anything being updated?  My suspicion is that there is an issue with the `.` or `0` characters.

Comment: UPDATE StudentInfo
SET HDCOD=REPLACE(HDCOD,'.0','.')
WHERE HDTYPID=3300                                                                                I have tried this. This will update the existing 3 decimals to 2. I'm trying to do update 3 decimal like 0001 to 001

Comment: @Johnson . . . This works on the data that you have provided in the question.  I have provided a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @Johnson . . . (1) Obviously, you can tweak the answer if that is what you really need.  That is not what the question describes, though ("For HDT 3300 I want to remove 0 in the decimal place. It should be CR100.001").  (2) This works on the data you provided and seems to do the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution using a [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) and [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql):

```
UPDATE StudentInfo 
    SET Code = REPLACE(Code, '.000', '.00') 
WHERE HDT = 3300 AND Code LIKE '%.000[1-9]';
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8bcb9d3c9f5b48bd2f473be36c95e73d)

---

You [asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128154/modify-existing-decimal-places-info) a few weeks ago to add a zero to the decimals. The accepted answer is the following:

```
UPDATE StudentInfo
SET HDCOD=REPLACE(HDCOD,'.','.0')
WHERE HDTYPID=3300
```

The exactly opposite of this solution to remove the added zero again would be the following (similar to @Gordon's solution):

```
UPDATE StudentInfo
SET HDCOD=REPLACE(HDCOD,'.0','.')
WHERE HDTYPID=3300
```

Comment: Wow, This completely deleted my decimals

Comment: Is not possible with the above query (see demo). Edit your question and show your `CREATE TABLE` of `StudentInfo` and the `INSERT` for the data. Also @Gordon's solution have to work. If it is not working with these two queries, we need more details!

Comment: I have tried this. This will update the existing 3 decimals to 2. I'm trying to do update 3 decimal like 0001 to 001.

Comment: Yes I know. The above solution (above the line) should work (see demo)! **If not provide more information so we can reproduce the issue (server version / create table command of StudentInfo and INSERT for data - some other important information we should know).** We just see your data and requirement and can only provide solutions for this. We can't access and see your database.